# Google Maps and event place

Tags: php, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have in my web site some events for user 
those events have a location 
i want to put a Google map for that 
this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);

function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But i have 2 problem

first problem is : how i can set the map to focus on Saudi Arabia 
second problem is : if we have event in some place how i put the location in map?

Comment: Lots of info on how to do that here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Answer (score 3):

Here is the javascript(say script.js file) for putting markers on map for the events(in your case):

```
var map = false;
var markers = [];

(function () {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDualhHxdg8nNCo4xY6gIfedyaHffW99UI&libraries=geometry,places&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(s);

})();


function initialize() {

    var geocoder = false;

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: 'grayscale',
        scrollwheel: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        rotateControlOptions: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false
    });

    map.mapTypes.set("grayscale", new google.maps.StyledMapType([{
        featureType: 'all',
        elementType: 'all',
        stylers: [{
            saturation: -80
        }]
    }], {
        name: 'Grey Scale'
    }));


    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        address: 'Saudi Arabia'
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            //this get the longitude and latitude of the saudi arabia
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());




            //this focuses on the saudi arabia
            map.setCenter(center);


            // Get the coordinates of the center of the map
            var center = map.getCenter();



            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {

            //ajax to get event location with longitude and latitude from database
                xhr = $.ajax({
                    url: '/joey/event',
                    data: {
                        param:"your param"
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        //then run loop over json data to add the markers on the map for the events
                        //code in loop start

                        // Here you can put the latitude and longtitude associated with event
                        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);


                        var event = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            title: "event name",
                            zIndex: 10000,
                            icon: 'event-icon.png',
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(jlat, jlng)
                        });
                        markers.push(event);
                        //code in loop end

                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });



}
```

In the html page simply put:

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
```

I hope this can be of some help to you.